# How do I pass view as an argument (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, arguments, viewmodel, swipe

I'm trying to move my fully functioning swipe gesture code into a `view model` to clean up the `view controller` but the code uses a lot of `self` and `view` references, so I suppose I need to pass along the `view` or `UIView.self` as an argument when calling the function. Can't get it to work though. Tried:

```
vm.swipeCode(myView: self.view)

func swipeCode(myView: UIView) {...
```

But it crashes. After some research I also tried variations of `inout` and `&` but to no avail. Here's the full swipe code (it references back to the `view controller` but I will move those as well when things start working :) )

```
var myVC = RecipesViewController()

func swipeCode(myView: UIView) {
    //SWIPE RIGHT
    let swipingRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
    swipingRight.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myVC.swipeRight))
    swipingRight.direction = .right
    swipingRight.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    swipingRight.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    myView.addGestureRecognizer(swipingRight)

    //// ALLOW SWIPE LEFT ////
    let swipingLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
    swipingLeft.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myVC.swipeLeft))
    swipingLeft.direction = .left
    swipingLeft.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    swipingLeft.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    myView.addGestureRecognizer(swipingLeft)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply make a `UIView` or `UIViewController` inherited class instead if your methods use a lot of `self` then simply make your controllers or views of that class.

```swift
class CustomViewController:UIViewController {
  func swipeCode(myView: UIView) {
    // Your code here
  }
  // Any other methods your code might need
}

class RecipesViewController:CustomViewController {
  // Whatever else your view controller is made from
}
```

Or if your code swiping works in every view controller you could also extends the `UIViewController` to add those functionnalities

Answer (score 0):

The crash is probably because of these two lines:

```
swipingRight.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myVC.swipeRight))
swipingLeft.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myVC.swipeLeft))
```

You passed `myVC.swipeLeft` as the action, but `self` as the target, so the gesture recogniser will try to find a `swipeLeft` method in `self`, which doesn't exist.

You should always ensure that the action is a member of the target:

```
swipingRight.addTarget(myVC, action: #selector(myVC.swipeRight))
swipingLeft.addTarget(myVC, action: #selector(myVC.swipeLeft))
```